# mobile website for iphone problems

Tags: iphone, html, web, mobile

I'm building a mobile version for a website, and i'm having some problems...

The main page of this mobile website is basically an image i made myself with this dimensions:

- width: 320px;
- height: 480px;

So, this in a normal pc browser is displayed with that dimensions... but in the iphone the image appears in the top left corner with a very small size at the eyes of the user... I'm using width:100%; in the css

This is the first time i'm making a mobile website, so any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to let the user to pinch zoom, just add to the content attribute "user-scalable=yes". 
Basically, the meta viewport allows you to set the scale of a webpage. It's very useful, precisely, for mobile webapps/websites