# correctly scaling website to display in iphone

Tags: html, css, mobile

I built a mobile website to fit 320px wide. In this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520064/mobile-website-for-iphone-problems) it throws out a useful piece of code to ensure that the iPhone displays it at the correct resolution, 320 wide. However, when I rotate the phone it doesn't automatically rescale to fit the wider viewport.

Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Some really useful information, thanks. I'm going to work through it and see what comes of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically size your content using [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries) [w3.org].

To detect when a mobile phone is portrait or landscape, use `orientation`, for instance:

```
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* apply your css styles here */
}
```

You can also chain together specific scenarios, depending on how specific you want to be. For instance, if you wanted to style a portrait browser with a device width of 400px you would do the following:

```
@media all and (orientation:landscape) and (device-width:400px) {
    /* apply your css styles here */
}
```

**It should be noted that media queries should be at the very end of your CSS files, otherwise they won't properly overwrite your existing styles.*

Answer (score 2):

For some of my mobile projects, I have been using an event listener for the resize event.  When the device shifts from portrait/landscape (or the desktop window resized) the event will be called and you can manually set the height and width of your elements.

Here is an short example of what I have been using:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizetick, false);
<...>
function resizetick(e) {
    if(this.resizet)
        clearTimeout(this.resizet);
        resizet = setTimeout(resizecallback, 100);
}
<...>
function resizecallback() {
    <if new resolution then resize elements here>
}
```

The purpose behind the setTimeout/clearTimeout is to prevent multiple resizes.  Desktop browser events are fired continually while resizing and mobile users may shift the direction of their device inadvertently. I want to avoid resizing the content repeatedly.

You'll need to bind or otherwise handle resize() and resizecallback().  I don't have a project handy to cut and paste working code from - sorry. :\

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell with out seeing the site but I'm gonna take a stab: your explicitly saying the website width is 320px, when you rotate it the width of the phone isn't such. Your wrapper should be `width: 100%` so that the document rescales it self or you rescale the viewport.